# Running x64 bit geoprocessing Python in Python IDLE 2.7.6 x64 error

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcpy, arcgis-10.2, installation

I am trying to set the Python IDLE 2.7.6 x64 to run the arcpy module from ArcGIS x64 bit geoprocessing (10.2.2). I copied the file DTBGGP64.pth from C:\Python27\ArcGISx6410.2\Lib\site-packages to C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages that is written as:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\bin64
C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\arcpy
C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\ArcToolbox\Scripts
```

when I then open the python 2.7.6 x64 IDLE and run the following command : import Arcpy, I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import arcpy
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\__init__.py", line 24,     in <module>
    from arcpy.toolbox import *
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\toolbox.py", line 356,     in <module>
    from management import Graph, GraphTemplate
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 22,     in <module>
    import _management
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\_management.py", line 14,     in <module>
    import _graph
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\_graph.py", line 27, in     <module>
    import numpy
 ImportError: No module named numpy
```

it seems to me that the 10.2.2 x64 bit python is pointing to the 32 bit python library. I have tried substituting the code from: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/...00000008000000

```
c:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2.2\arcpy
c:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2.2\bin
c:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2.2\ArcToolbox\Scripts
```

I get the error that it cannot even find the arcpy module.
My ultimate goal is to get the arcpy module to run in spss 22 which is built on the Python 2.7.1 x64 framework. However even when I put the DTBGGP64.pth file in the site-packages folder of that module, I get the same exact traceback error that it cannot find Numpy

Any thought on how to solve this?

Comment: So you installed your own 64bit Python at "C:\Python27\"? If you're doing your own install you'll also have to install numpy and matplotlib (and maybe 1 or 2 more packages I dont recall off the top of my head). Keep in mind 10.2.2 uses Python 2.7.5. Yes thats only 0.0.4 versions off of 2.7.1, but there might be some dependencies that dont allow you to go back [just speculating, havent tested one way or another to confirm]

Comment: I can change the SPSS directory from 2.7.1 to 2.7.6 in the software itself. It seems to be able to be changed at anytime back and forth (as long as a dataset is not open)I have not tested it other than trying to run arcpy through the 2.7.1 IDLE.

Comment: to install numpy and matlotlib, it is not exactly clear where I install those packages, or how to install them correctly.  DO I install them into the ArcGIS python (x64) or into the python 2.7.6 (x64)?

Comment: If SPSS can use ArcGIS 64bit BG install, why not use that? You're done: because its already setup and ready to go. If you're rolling your own python, the numpy and matplotlib installs should find the 64bit python install and put them in there when installing. (those installers get that information from the registry)

Comment: Thanks for the help, and you are right, I did just find your first solution from your last post that got the desired affect.  I wish I could I mark your post as the correct answer!

Comment: @KHibma When you get a chance it would be great if you could copy/paste from your comment(s) into an answer. It looks like the asker is keen to accept.

Answer (score 0):

As commented by @KHibma:

> If SPSS can use ArcGIS 64bit BG install, why not use that? You're
>   done: because its already setup and ready to go. If you're rolling
>   your own python, the numpy and matplotlib installs should find the
>   64bit python install and put them in there when installing. (those
>   installers get that information from the registry)

Answer (score -1):

After you copy all files from `C:\Python27\ArcGISx6410.2\Lib\site-packages` to `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages`,  you should add a new system variable called `PYTHONPATH` and its value `c:\python27\lib, c:\python27\Lib\site-packages`

Please check details on the following link:

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//002z00000008000000